# C++ i create a output file during runtime , how can i read this output file as a input again?

Tags: c++

```
ifstream fin1( "input.txt" );
```

...some coed here...

then i generate the following output file

```
ofstream fout("output.txt");
```

....some code.....

try to use it in my code again

```
ifstream fin1( "output.txt" );

string a,b,c,d;
 while(fin1 >> a >> b >> c >> d)
 {
 cout<<a<<" 1 "<<b<<" 2 " <<c<<" 3 " <<d<<" 4 "<<endl;

 }
```

...try to print out the content and it won't work

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to call `fout.close()` before you opened `fin1`?